# How to send an IM in C or C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

Specifically I am talking about using AIM and sending instant messages to an existing AIM screename. How would I accomplish this? I am trying to do it the simplest way possible -efficiency is not that important.

I thought maybe all I would have to do is open a socket connections some how but I am probably wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I would use [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple).  It's a multi-platform C library that supports many IM services, including AIM.

Comment: No, of course not.  But I would recommend using a library.  Among other reasons, AIM has a history of deliberately [breaking interoperability](http://www.pcworld.com/article/86024/im_interoperability_stalled_aol_battles_trillian.html) to lock users in.  libpurple can probably keep up faster than you alone.

Comment: It probably isn't the only way - you probably can do it by opening a socket connection to the server and sending through the right sort of message. However you need to know the protocol between client/server to be able to do this successfully. The library suggested here probably implements that protocol.

Comment: I can't find a good guide that shows how to implement libpurple into a simple program :/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source for [GAIM/Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/), which runs on a variety of platforms including windows. It uses a modified version of [libfaim](http://www.zigamorph.net/libfaim/).